# Is there any other way of servlet instance get created?

Tags: java, servlets

I like to know is there any other way servlet instance get created. One way is when client makes a first request to the servlet.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify servlet creation/running on startup of the container.

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>TestServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

specifies a startup order. The above specifies that `TestServlet` will start on container startup, and be the first (hence `1`).

I often prefer servlets starting during container startup. It allows them to perform any time-consuming initialisation prior to client interaction.

EDIT: As Skaffman pointed out below, `0` means start on first request.

Comment: And a zero value means startup on first request, not just the ordering